# Is there any rules that which part of sql statement clause can be used in condition/case expression?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

the select clause/where clause in select statement seems can use if/case expression

which I have see many times.

Can this statement be used by if/case expression?

```
alter table drop foreign key xxx
```

if not then, is there any rules about that which sql statement/clause can be used in if/case expression?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any expression that returns a boolean value i.e. TRUE / FALSE can be used in WHERE or IF/ELSE clause.